# A lock-free data structure that doesn't have race condition

Tags: operating-system

In my OS class, we have an exercise about how can modify a lock-free stack code that it becomes free from  race condition, but I don't get how a lock-free data structure can have a race condition and how CAS works here. and the question is :

The compare and swap() instruction can be used to design lock-free
data structures such as stacks, queues, and lists. The program example
shown below presents a possible solution to a lock-free stack
using CAS instructions, where the stack is represented as a linked list
of Node elements with top representing the top of the stack. Is this implementation free from race conditions?(i can't solve it)

```
typedef struct node {
    value t data;
    struct node* next;
} Node;

Node* top; // top of stack
void push(value t item)
{
    Node* old node;
    Node* new node;
    new node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new node->data = item;
    do {
        old node = top;
        new node->next = old node;
    } while (compare and swap(top, old node, new node) != old node);
}

value t pop()
{
    Node* old node;
    Node* new node;
    do {
        old node = top;
        if (old node == NULL)
            return NULL;
        new node = old node->next;
    } while (compare and swap(top, old node, new node) != old node);
    return old node->data;
}
```

Comment: `Node* old node;` is not valid C++. `new node = malloc(sizeof(Node));` is not valid C++. `compare and swap(top, old node, new node)` is also not valid C++. Looks like about half the lines in the shown code would not compile. If your question is related to C++, can you show real C++ code, and explain what your question is, regarding the shown code?

Comment: my main question is "Is this implementation free from race conditions?" @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Yes, race conditions afflict only code that can be run. This will not compile (see above comment), so in that sense, it is trivially safe from race conditions.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot. @dratenik

Comment: Oh, interesting! thank you.@dratenik

Comment: I'm actually being a bit difficult on purpose. This looks like you brought us your homework and went "I can't solve this". Well, have you tried? Is there a way the code could go wrong if any two parts of it run at the same time?

Comment: And could it go wrong in some way if you replaced the compare_and_swap calls with a plain assignment `top=new_node`?

Comment: Can you write C++ that compiles?  If you cannot write C++ that compiles, then trying to write C++ lock free code is the wrong level of problem to solve; it is like trying to learn calculus when you don't know what 1+1 is.  If you can write C++ code that compiles, please provide it. If you can't yet write C++, go practice writing relatively simple C++ code and come back in a week or few when writing valid C++ is a skill you have.  Lock free code is tricky; distiguishing between "psuedo code typo" and "actual error" makes your problem dozens of times harder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a demonstration of what a race can look like. Let's replace the compare_and_swap with a plain assignment:

```
void push(value_t item)
{
    Node* old_node;
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = item;
        old_node = top;
        new_node->next = old_node;
    top = new_node;
}
```

This will do the same thing in single thread, but should be prone to races in multithread.

Now let's run two of those at the same time (simulated by adding a second copy of everything). What could go wrong?

```
void push(value_t item, value_t item2)
{
    Node* old_node;
    Node* old_node2;
    Node* new_node;
    Node* new_node2;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node2 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = item;
    new_node2->data = item2;
        old_node = top;
        old_node2 = top;
        new_node->next = old_node;
        new_node2->next = old_node2;
    top = new_node;
    top = new_node2;
}
```

And the result of `top = new_node` gets immediately overwritten by `top = new_node2` so in the end we have only inserted `item2`, the value of `item` got lost.

The core problem there is access to shared memory, namely the `top` variable. Both threads read it, thread 1 updated it, thread 2 continued using the now out-of-date value and made its own update based on that.

That's what the compare_and_swap loops are there to prevent.

Comment: So CAS  function transfers the "top value" from "old node" to "new node" without losing the value of some nodes, Hence this code is free from race condition.